# A very Strange SQL of PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a Strange SQL in our PostgreSQL SERVER, version 8.4.  It is looks like a system sql which excuted by PG server ! I have no idea about this sql? Anyone know this ?

--Strange sql

```
SELECT NULL AS TABLE_CAT, 
       n.nspname AS TABLE_SCHEM, 
       c.relname AS TABLE_NAME,  
       CASE n.nspname ~ '^pg_' OR n.nspname = 'information_schema'  
          WHEN true THEN 
            CASE 
               WHEN n.nspname = 'pg_catalog' OR n.nspname = 'information_schema' THEN 
                 CASE c.relkind   
                   WHEN 'r' THEN 'SYSTEM TABLE'   
                   WHEN 'v' THEN 'SYSTEM VIEW'   
                   WHEN 'i' THEN 'SYSTEM INDEX'   
                   ELSE NULL   
                 END  
               WHEN n.nspname = 'pg_toast' THEN 
                 CASE c.relkind 
                   WHEN 'r' THEN 'SYSTEM TOAST TABLE'   
                   WHEN 'i' THEN 'SYSTEM TOAST INDEX'   
                   ELSE NULL   
                 END  
               ELSE 
                 CASE c.relkind   
                   WHEN 'r' THEN 'TEMPORARY TABLE'   
                   WHEN 'i' THEN 'TEMPORARY INDEX'   
                   ELSE NULL   
                 END  
             END  
             WHEN false THEN 
               CASE c.relkind  
                 WHEN 'r' THEN 'TABLE'  
                 WHEN 'i' THEN 'INDEX'  
                 WHEN 'S' THEN 'SEQUENCE'  
                 WHEN 'v' THEN 'VIEW'  
                 ELSE NULL  
               END  
             ELSE NULL  
           END  AS TABLE_TYPE, 
           d.description AS REMARKS  
      FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n, 
           pg_catalog.pg_class c  
 LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_description d ON (c.oid = d.objoid 
                                      AND d.objsubid = 0)  
 LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class dc ON (d.classoid = dc.oid 
                                 AND dc.relname='pg_class'
```

Comment: My eyes.. Please format it with the proper coding tags in the editor so its readable.

Comment: Post unformated code like that again, and I won't help.  If SO can't read your issue, SO won't help.

Comment: Are you talking about `CASE n.nspname ~ '^pg_'` in the query?

Comment: sorry, I will format next time.

Comment: @francs, you have posted seven questions and have not voted a single time for a good answer, and never accepted an answer. This is a community, such a behavior will not make people help you happily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is part of the `getTables()` implementation in the postgresql JDBC driver.

**Update**

While Google Code Search was retired a few years after this answer was originally posted, you can see this logic today in the [pgjdbc "meta data" sources](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/e912c6c7a495cb0cfaba96dbbf56caee540ce9f9/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgDatabaseMetaData.java#L1271).

Comment: The only "impact" is that you get a list of tables. Enjoy! :-)

Comment: Hi,intgr, did you see this SQL in your product database?

Comment: When does the function getTables() will be excuted?  It's controled by the application code?

Comment: @francs the driver is probably just doing some internal stuff. this query doesn't even work on my postgres installation, so it's showing up a lot on my log. don't know if this is your case too, but i'll try to fix it switching to a different version of the driver.

Comment: See this: http://www.postgresql-archive.org/System-Query-hit-to-Database-td5886965.html

Answer (score 1):

This problem also occures when  your application uses some connection manager like c3p0. C3P0 has option `preferredTestQuery` which defines a query to be executed before acquiring a connection from pool of connection.

If you didn't set this option it would do some weird sql query, otherwise you can tell it to use `preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1`

Comment: It's still the JDBC driver running that statement because c3p0's has a pretty stupid default configuration that uses `getTables()` to validate a connection.

Comment: I guess this is the c3p0 problem and not the JDBC driver, `getTables()` works as it should to.

Comment: We have the same query in our app, but we don't use c3p0. So I guess it's not exactly the cause.